# How can I avoid download something repeatedly with gsutil?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

Now I am downloading something quite large (570.8GB) with Google Cloud SDK Shell.

Every time when I decide to terminate the download and start again (I can barely use this computer to do anything else when I was downloading with gsutil because of multi-thread downloading enabled), it would always start from scratch as if nothing had been downloaded before, which is quite frustrating.

May I ask how can I prevent downloading from scratch repeatedly?

p.s. 
Now I am using this line argument for my downloading:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://xxxxx/ destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Resumable downloads are supported according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#resumable-transfers):

> Similarly, gsutil automatically performs resumable downloads (using standard HTTP Range GET operations) whenever you use the cp command, unless the destination is a stream. In this case, a partially downloaded temporary file will be visible in the destination directory. Upon completion, the original file is deleted and overwritten with the downloaded contents.
>
> Resumable uploads and **downloads store state information in files under ~/.gsutil**, named by the destination object or file. If you attempt to resume a transfer from a machine with a different directory, the transfer will start over from scratch.

You can check if state information is present on the corresponding path.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot see any temporary file available in the destination directory, which is what troublesome. I thought that my situation might be something different from resumable downloads so I just avoided using that term initially.  Thank you anyway.